# How can I change text size of tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, text-size

I want to change the text size of the strings which is in the tabhost. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

**1.Adding Theme to Activity via Style-XML**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" >
<item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Then in your `androidManifest.xml` you specify the theme above for your `TabActivity` or `Activity` containing your `TabWidget`:

```
<activity android:name="MyTabActivity" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

**2. Styling Indicator of TabHost via Code**

```
TextView textTab = new TextView(this);
textTab.setText("TAB-INDICATOR");
textTab.setTextSize(18);
textTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB1").setIndicator(textTab).setContent(new Intent(this, Your.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```